# estimation of speed function in level set methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a series of images which shows the evolution of a boundary. I am trying to estimate the speed function by using the level set methods. So it is an inverse problem. I have images which show the evolution of boundary. By using them I need to estimate the force function which makes the boundary evolve. I am actually searching for any research related to this topic. If anyone can give me a reference of a paper or a code I would be very glad.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Level sets do not have enough information to decide the speed function. For example, if you do simple level set, $x^2+y^2 - r^2 = 0$, for a circle, then the information required to separate different points in a circle comes from $(r \cos (a), r \sin(a)), a \in [0..2\pi]$, with $a$ separating the points and recovering this in case of general level sets seems extreamly difficult. Speed function can be found whenever each image the points on the boundary can be "separated", and then matched to points in different image with the same identification. This gives a vector (in 2d) for each point in the boundary.

afterthought: Hmm, ray tracing a level set is possible, so speed function can be recovered from "any" direction, if you arbitrarily choose a ray, and then find the boundary. But it doesn't give you all the information needed.

Comment: If we restrict the motion of points to always be in the normal directions, can we then calculate the speed function?